# Erro no php mailer

Tags: php, envio-de-email, phpmailer

estou usando a função phpmailer, segue as configurações:

```
$file  = str_replace($comacento, $acentohtml, $file);
    require_once('../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    require_once('../phpmailer/class.pop3.php'); // required for POP before SMTP
    require_once('../phpmailer/class.smtp.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "mail.catalogovirtualnossacasa.com.br"; // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                               // 1 = errors and messages
                                               // 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMPTAuth = true;                     // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Port       = 587;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "contato@catalogovirtualnossacasa.com.br"; // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "******";        // SMTP account password

    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['nome']);

    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['nome']);

    $mail->Subject = 'loja '.$_POST['email'].' & Grupo Nossa Casa ';

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail->MsgHTML($file);
    $mail->isHTML(true); 

    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['email'], "Compra - Grupo Nossa Casa");
    if($mail->Send()){
        echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert(\"ok!\");
        </script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert(\"deu ruim\");
        </script>";
    }
```

apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /var/sentora/hostdata/gnc/public_html/adm_catalogovirtualnossacasa_com_br/phpmailer/class.smtp.php on line 248
SMTP -> ERROR: RSET failed: KGA�rh��    OkA4O��#��:8f�F,ol� Xe[�q�����Q�*&p�z��n�DL��͸03l��cZ���q_�G�_���i��2rJ�v.�A�WV��hR�^�3g7~k"+A�&���>Jx���`ߦ̈y�/�Q����J�s����1-{o�����+#�6M� �C�pKſ4�*3@Y�M1l�jJ@@!`�L9�q��\~���s<�;��[�u�Q����l���'I\"�J�d}]����@�q�Q�`�>���=��<�τ�I5kVe� ����cu�   ;����y?B�ל �/L&���W��%:�����[S 
SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedThe following From address failed: tuliogomes07@hotmail.com
```

Comment: reproduzi no meu servidor e não deu ruim não

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo teria como me passa seu whats ou skype pra gente poder trocar uma ideia melhor

Comment: Pelo que me lembro necessário **habilitar** a porta 587. Há algumas formas de enviar e-mail que necessita de uma "autorização" através do próprio e-mail. Há casos que o host interfere, tente configurar no painel. Qual é o host?

Comment: @TulioVieira qual host você está utilizando? ou está em localhost?

Comment: Por favor não use Trecho de código (Stack Snippets) para PHP, leia: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/3635

Comment: @Rafaelgss uso onclickhosting mas já resolvi o problema

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso uso onclickhosting e ja resolvi meu problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto não é um problema com portas, isto é um problema com certificados de segurança, se o vosso servidor por padrão não tiver configurado o SSL, principalmente a partir do ***PHP 5.6***:

> http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php

No seu php.ini não deve estar configurado um dos seguintes campos:

- `openssl.cafile=`
- `openssl.capath=`

Ou então teu servidor não tem OpenSSL instalado, no entanto é possivel configurar manualmente através do `stream_context_create`, por exemplo:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer'   => true,
        'verify_depth'  => 5,
        'peer_name'     => 'HOST que está tentando acessar'
    );
));
```

E um **detalhe importante**, pela sua mensagem de erro:

> ... phpmailer/class.smtp.php on line 248

Você claramente não baixou o *PHPMailer* do site oficial mantido, pois nas verões atuais os nomes dos scripts são diferentes, veja o repositório oficial:

- https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Este provavelmente tem maior compatibilidade com as mudanças do PHP5.6 e 7, portanto não baixe de fontes aleatórias, busque sempre o oficial (claro que existem exceções, mas sempre tem o risco de não funcionar).

### Como resolver problemas de SSL no PHPMailer

Primeiro baixe a versão mais atualizada do PHPMailer, ele usa composer-autoload, mas se você baixar o https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases/tag/v6.0.1 (versão mais atual até agora) e depois extrair em sua pasta o seu script deverá ficar assim:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once '../PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require_once '../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once '../PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

... Resto do arquivo que vem antes do seu str_replace deve ficar AQUI!!! ...

$file  = str_replace($comacento, $acentohtml, $file);

...
```

E então ajuste teu script pra algo semelhante a isto e teste:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp1.foobar.com';                     // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
    $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
    $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

    //Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

### Ajustando parametros SSL no php.ini

Se o upgrade não resolver o problema é porque o teu servidor está "mal" configurado

E verifique se o OpenSSL está instalado e então primeiramente tente configurar via php.ini os parâmetros que lhe citei conforme o teu OpenSSL:

- `openssl.cafile=`
- `openssl.capath=`

### Configurando SSL diretamente no PHPMailer

Agora se você não tem acesso ao servidor recomendo que realmente entre em contato com o suporte técnico, mas se acaso não puder ser feito isto você pode tentar a solução manual, usando `SMTPOptions`, será necessário ter o `ca_cert.pem` e no `peer_name` configurar o caminho do HOST do SMTP:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.foobar.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';
$mail->Password = 'secret';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => true,
        'verify_depth' => 3,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
        'peer_name' => $mail->Host, //Mesmo endereço do HOST
        'cafile' => '/etc/ssl/ca_cert.pem',
    ],
);
```